# Probability on statistics

Tags: probability

Consider a game in which a fair coin is flipped an a fair six sided die is rolled. A player wins if the number on the die is smaller than or equal to 2 , or if the coin is a tail and the number on the die is a 6. How many outcomes are there in the sample space and what is the probability That the player  loses any particular game?

Comment: There are $6\cdot 2=12$ outcomes (write them out), and each are equally likely. To determine the probability of losing a game, count the number of outcomes that correspond to a loss (you can do this by inspection), and divide by $12$ (the size of the sample space).

Answer (score 1):

My stab w/ this stuff (which I'm not that good at but preparing for w/ GRE prep)

Probability of getting $\leq 2$ on die: $2/6$

Probability of getting a tail AND a 6 on the die: $1/12$ ($1/2$ for coin toss $\cdot 1/6$ for die roll)

Total probability of win: $2/6 + 1/12 = 5/12$.  Thus, probability to lose $= 7/12$.

Someone correct me if I messed that up.

Comment: Thanks for the edits.  For my benefit, what is the standard here?  I'm used to Stack Exchange which uses 4 spaces for code.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  You can use LaTeX or MathML.

Comment: Cheers.  I got some learning to do. :)